# Caracteres basura (ï»¿) entre headers y el contenido, usando nusoap

Tags: php, apache2

Desarrollé un Web Service usando nusoap(0.9.5), que tengo instalado en varios hostings de proveedores diferentes. Estos hostings tienen Apache (supongo que 2.4) y PHP en distintas versiones (5.2, 5.4 y 5.6). En todos ellos funcionaba perfectamente el Web Service.

La cuestión está en que en dos de estos hostings, después de funcionar perfectamente por algún tiempo, los "clientes" que se conectan al web service marcan el error "**No es posible pasar de la codificación actual a la especificada**". Este mismo error lo marca IExplore al acceder al WSDL del web service "servicio.php?wsdl" (Firefox sólo omite el error).

Al principio creí que se trataba de un error en la codificación usada en el web service, pero: 
- El encabezado de respuesta del servidor marca **Content-Type: text/xml; charset=ISO-8859-1** 
- La respuesta del web service coincide con ella  **<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>** 
- Es la misma codificación que esperan los clientes.

Usando las herramientas de desarrollador de Firefox, encontré qué era lo que estaba causando el error, unos caracteres "basura" antes de iniciar la respuesta del web service (los 3 caracteres antes del <):

```
ï»¿<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-..........
```

Así que supongo que el error del "cambio de codificación" marcado por los clientes que se conectan al web service, se debe a que, al iniciar el parsing de la respuesta, encuentran esos caracteres que les hace suponer que la respuesta está en UTF-8, y poco más adelante al encontrar la codificación declarada marcan el error.

Extrayendo algunas líneas de nusoap.php, del método send_response() de la clase nusoap_server (entre las líneas 4208 y 4276), vemos cómo se envía la respuesta del servicio web:

```
function send_response() {
    ...
    $payload = $this->responseSOAP;
    ...
    $this->outgoing_headers[] = "Content-Length: ".strlen($payload);
    reset($this->outgoing_headers);
    foreach($this->outgoing_headers as $hdr){
        header($hdr, false);
    }
    print $payload;
    ...
```

Como pueden ver, en el foreach se envían los encabezados, así que no se ha enviado nada más al cliente (de haberlo hecho, la función header se hubiera quejado con algo como "headers already sent").

Inmediatamente después de enviar los encabezados, se imprime $payload, que es la respuesta del servicio web, desde el <?xml version="1.0" .... hasta cerrar la respuesta.

¿De dónde vienen los 3 caracteres basura que estoy recibiendo en los clientes?

Nota: Yo también pensé que $payload tenía los caracteres basura, pero si modifico la línea:

```
   print $payload;
```

Por esta otra:

```
   print "A123".$payload;
```

Ahora en los clientes recibo la respuesta:

```
ï»¿A123<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-
```

Les recuerdo que este error apareció de repente.

No sé si en los hostings (2 que fallan de 5 donde está instalado) hicieron alguna actualización de Apache o PHP.

Esto es lo que he intentado:

1. Copié todo mi código de uno de los hostings donde funciona correctamente el web service a otro donde no funciona, y siguió sin funcionar.
2. En el CPanel de un hosting fallando, he seleccionado la misma versión y  módulos de PHP para igualar la configuración de otro que funciona correctamente. Sigue sin funcionar.

Agradeceré la ayuda, pero después de 39 horas de estar buscando una solución, creo que es caso perdido.

Gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Esos "extraños" caracteres que te aparecen son llamados [Byte Order Mark](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marca_de_orden_de_bytes)

> La marca de orden de bytes (del inglés byte order mark o BOM) es un carácter Unicode que se utiliza para indicar el orden de los bytes de un fichero de texto. Además de usarse para indicar el orden de los bytes, también se puede utilizar como marca para indicar qué codificación Unicode se está utilizando (UTF-8, UTF-16 o UTF-32).

Para solucionarlo puedes abrir el archivo por ejemplo con notepad++, ir a encoding y cambiarlo a "UTF-8" sin BOM.

Luego vuelve a subirlo a los servidores problemáticos y debería solucionarse tu problema.

Espero que te sirva, Saludos!

Comment: Pero cómo va a modificar un archivo si los XML se generan dinámicos?

Comment: @Alfabravo me refería al/los archivo .php que utiliza para generar el .xml